# How to get the value of an HTML element attribute that added from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have added an attribute **isAdmin** to an HTML tag as below:

```
Partial Class Controls_View_ViewOrder
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)

    Dim isAdmin = Page.RouteData.Values("UserAdmn")
    rowMenu.Attributes.Add("isadmin", isAdmin)

End Sub
End Class
```

Trying to get the value of **isAdmin** by JavaScript as below:

```
<div class="rowMenu" id="rowMenu" runat="server"> </div>
.
.
.
let isAdmin = document.getElementById("rowMenu").getAttribute("isadmin");
```

but I got the below error:
[image]

When I try to get the value of **isAdmin** I got error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

`<div class="rowMenu" id="rowMenu" runat="server"> </div>`

Please write the code in this way:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Scrap._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <div class="rowMenu" id="rowMenu" isadmin="<%= Page.RouteData.Values("UserAdmn") %>" > </div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                let isAdmin = document.getElementById("rowMenu").getAttribute("isadmin");
                alert(isAdmin);
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it didn't work! I added the `ClinetIdMode` to the div:
`<div class="rowMenu" id="rowMenu" ClientIDMode="Static" >` AND tried to get the value like this: `document.getElementById("<%= rowMenu.ClientId %>").getAttribute("isadmin");` AND removed `runat="server"`

Comment: tried them all separately, could you update your answer? for the options 1 or 2?

Comment: still not working.

Comment: I need to add the `isadmin` attr from the code behind! using this `rowMenu.Attributes.Add("isadmin", isAdmin)` when i remove the `runat="server"` I got compilation error!

Comment: your solution doesn't work

Comment: @AliAlAmine I have amended my answer with code I have tested and run in visual studio.